# RVM::IncompatibleRubyError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run a sample rails application on a server but am unable to do so and just keep getting this message.

Error message:
The given ruby environment requires ruby-1.9.3-p392 (versus ruby-1.9.3-p374) (RVM::IncompatibleRubyError)

I think it means I have to change my version of ruby? Is it possible to do it in command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what ruby versions you have installed type:

```
rvm list
```

If version you need is not listed type:

```
rvm get head
```

this will upgrade to the most stable version of rvm(optional step).

To list all version available to install type:

```
rvm list known
```

To install version you need type:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

Now you can double check it with:

```
rvm list
```

and type:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

to use it.

if you would like your new version to be default version add --default flag to rvm use command

```
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

There is few more other flags like --system for example, check [rvm home page](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/) for more info.

**UPDATE**

Some how I just assume that you are using rvm, but after rereading your answer I didn't find any information about it(my brain lag).

RVM is a Ruby Version Manager(there is few others out there) and it helps you with installing new versions of ruby and managing installed ones. I recommend you to use some sort of ruby version manager and RVM is a good choice.

If you need info about how to install it let me know or check the link i gave you for installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, and you can do it using command line,

if you have the corresponding ruby version installed

## this would switch to the below ruby version

> rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392

## If you want to install using the command

> rvm  install ruby-1.9.3-p392

and use it using rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392